# Run Cucumber-Selenium Tests in an Embedded QT Browser

Tags: c++, qt, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gwt

I have a GWT application that is embedded inside a C++ Desktop application. I need to launch Selenium tests from the same browser that is embedded inside the application. 
The browser I am using is IE (or) QT Browser. Any thoughts on how it can be done?

Appreciate your help in advance. 
Thanks

Comment: Hello, as of right now I don't think it is possible, Selenium running IEdriver, which is stand alone instance of IE browser for automation, your Desktop IE Browser not used by Selenium.

Comment: Let me simplify the question. 
I have a GWT application. From the application, I want to trigger cucumber test , may be on click of a button or something.?

Answer (score 0):

You can as long as you are able to do a Dom manipulation of the GWT Application from selenium.

Question is how do you intend to attach a selenium to the browser which is running within c++ application. Does the browser which runs inside the c++ application has it's own process space. if then you can try plugging selenium to that using driver session.

But i am not sure whether all these can be achieved in an QT. But in IE (may be).